# Can someone help me solve the following exercise?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can someone help me solve the following exercise.

Show that if $\Phi \in \mathrm{D}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\int \Phi(x) dx = 0$ if and only if there is $\Psi \in \mathrm{D}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\Phi =\Psi'$.

$\mathrm{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is an infinitely differentiable set of functions with compact support.

If there is $\Psi \in \mathrm{D}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\Phi =\Psi'$ then  $\int \Phi(x) dx = 0$ is easy.

Comment: What is a candidate for $\Psi$ such that $\Phi = \Psi'$?The inverse of differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $\Phi$ to define $\Psi$ through integration. The idea is to use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that $\Phi= \Psi'$ and use the fact that $\int\Phi=0$ to show that $\Psi$ has compact support. To make it precise, define;

\begin{equation}
\Psi(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(t)\text{ d}t.
\end{equation}

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
\begin{equation}
\Phi'(x)= \Phi(x)- \lim_{t\to-\infty} \Phi(t)= \Phi(x),
\end{equation}
because the limit goes to 0 since $\Phi$ is compactly supported.

We now need to show that $\Psi$ has compact support. Let $M>0$ such that $\Phi(x)=0$ when $x\notin[-M, M]$. It is clear that for $x<M$,
\begin{equation}
\Psi(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(t)\text{ d}t= \int_{-\infty}^x 0\text{ d}t=0.
\end{equation}
Moreover, if $x>M$ then,
\begin{equation}
\Phi(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(t)\text{ d}t= \int_{-\infty}^x \Phi(t)\text{ d}t+ \int_{x}^\infty \Phi(t)\text{ d}t= \int\Phi=0. 
\end{equation}
The second equality holds because $\Phi$ vanishes in $(x,\infty)\subset (M, \infty)$ and hence its like adding $0$.

This shows that $\Psi$ is supported in $[-M, M]$.